Audio resource not found on Android with react-sound
I have a react-native project with built-in audio that works fine in iOS, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work on Android.
On iOS, I simply have to open XCode and add my audio folder to the project.
In Android, I have not figured out how to do this.
What I have tried is this:

Adding the audio to my assets folder
Adding "./assets/audio/" to the assets section of my react-native-config.js file
Running npx react-native-asset

My audio files were a mix of upper/lowercase of letters and numbers.
Two issues I encountered was that I had to change my audio files to lowercase and also had remove numbers from the start of file names (added a prefix of "a_" to every file). Not sure if there is a way to allow for numbers and uppercase audio names, but it's a hassle having to change them when switching to Android.
However, even after doing this, it still does not work.
For iOS I have used:
path = "audio/" + soundfile
base_path = Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE

var s = new Sound(path, base_path, (e) => {
    if (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    } else {
        s.play(()=>{
            s.release()
        })
    }
});

However, this does not work on Android. I have discovered that Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE is returning "undefined". I have tried setting base_path to an empty string '' instead. But still not having any luck.
My path has been modified to be:
path = "./assets/audio/a_" + soundfile.toLowerCase()

to handle the new audio file names (letter at beginning and lower case).
I have verified that the path is correct and points to the proper file.
The Error:
However, I am still getting

error {"code": -1, "message": "resource not found"}

Questions:
Main Question: What else should I be doing so the audio will play?
Secondary Question: Is there an easier way to do this without needing my filenames to be lowercase and unable to start with a number?

This seems to solve my problem:
path = "a_" + soundfile.toLowerCase()
base_path = ''

var s = new Sound(path, base_path, (e) => {
    if (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    } else {
        s.play(()=>{
            s.release()
        })
    }
});

It seems that running the command npx react-native-asset copies the audio files directly into android/app/src/main/res/raw/. Apparently sub-directories are not allowed in the raw directory, so I cannot have my audio directory in here.
